# is Java cms MAGNOLIA free to use for commercial sites

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

Someone just told me to use [MAGNOLIA](http://www.magnolia-cms.com/)

cms for java.

I just want to know that is it free to use for commercial sites.

I dont want to waste some time learn it and then i find that i need to spend money to use.

I read the website but could not found the diff between free and enterprise use.

as i don't know much java i was not able to find whether those paid features are required for many sites or not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They have community (free) and enterprise (licensed) versions:

http://www.magnolia-cms.com/magnolia-cms/pricing.html

Here are the features that the enterprise edition provides:

http://www.magnolia-cms.com/magnolia-cms/editions/enterprise-edition.html

The community edition uses the GPL v3 license.  Here are the terms:

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

Comment: Here are current links to the edition's comparison:
https://www.magnolia-cms.com/magnolia/ce-ee.html
and the Community Edition's registration page:
https://www.magnolia-cms.com/magnolia/ce-registration.html.

You may also use Magnolia with Maven withour registration. (Link on the right of the CE-page).

Comment: Thank you.  Six years after the fact this might be helpful.  Are you affiliated with Magnolia in some way?  I wouldn't like advertising for them/you.

Comment: I'm not affiliated with them. We just use Magnolia in our company and sometimes new staff asks why we always state that it's free, while there is no free version on their website.
The EE has more features, compared to the CE, but if you don't need these, like us, you can stick to the free version.

Didn't realise, this question was that old. It's a question I still get asked quite often.

Answer (score 2):

The link you posted http://www.magnolia-cms.com/magnolia-cms/pricing.html may have changed its content since posting but currently it does NOT show the prices for the CMS .. just a list of "features" and a "contact us" button.
I have tried for an hour to find ANY mention of the price for Magnolia CMS and its hidden from View. The best I can find is "starts at $12,000" no mention where it ends.
If they can't put down in an easy to find place a simple list of their prices I for one would steer clear of them.
Cheers John

Comment: Many companies don't show actual prices. In this segment you have to ask for an estimate and they will make a customised plan for you...

Comment: 20-60k USD net per year as of middle 2018, depending on needs and configuration stack. As zoku said -- all estimable and customizable directly for you (your company).